# Issue adding relating Firebase records

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To give context - I have successfully implemented in my application to allow me to add `tenants` to `properties`.  However, at the moment when I add a `tenant`, it is then present in all the property records that I bring up in my application.

I was wondering if there was a way I could relate the `propertyID` of each of the `properties` and `tenantID` when adding `tenants`.  The result of this would be only the tenants added to a particular property would only be viewable at that property (not at all properties as they are now).

Hopefully this makes sense, apologies for any vagueness.

Here is some of my code for further clarification (Apologies for code dump):

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_tenants);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        databaseTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants");
        databaseTenantsList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(uid);

        textViewPropertyName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPropertyName);
        editTextTenantsName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTenantsName);
        seekBarAge = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarAge);

        buttonAddTenant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTenant);

        listViewTenants = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTenants);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        tenants = new ArrayList<>();

        String id = intent.getStringExtra(PropertyActivity.PROPERTY_ID);
        String name = intent.getStringExtra(PropertyActivity.PROPERTY_NAME);

        textViewPropertyName.setText(name);

        buttonAddTenant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveTenant();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseTenantsList.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tenants.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot tenantSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tenant tenant = tenantSnapshot.getValue(Tenant.class);

                    tenants.add(tenant);
                }

                TenantList tenantListAdapter = new TenantList(AddTenantsActivity.this, tenants);
                listViewTenants.setAdapter(tenantListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void saveTenant() {

        String tenantName = editTextTenantsName.getText().toString().trim();
        int age = seekBarAge.getProgress();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tenantName)){

            String id = databaseTenants.push().getKey();

            Tenant tenant = new Tenant(id, tenantName, age);

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();

            databaseTenants.child(uid).child(id).setValue(tenant);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tenant saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tenant name should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Shown here is my data structure:

[image: Data Structure]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you give us an example of what you want to achieve?